ModuleNotFoundError When Running Python Script in Visual Studio Code althogh this is the root directory of the project
I'm having trouble importing a module in my Python project while using Visual Studio Code. I receive a ModuleNotFoundError, indicating that Python cannot find the defmet_data_piplines module.
Project Structure
Here’s an overview of my project directory:
C:\projects\defmet  
│  
├── defmet_data_piplines  
│   ├── __init__.py       
│   ├── app  
│   │   ├── __init__.py    
│   │   ├── main.py  
│   │   
│   ├── ...  
├── notebooks  
├── venv  
└── ...  

Error Message
When I run my script (main.py), I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'defmet_data_piplines'
Current Configuration
I have the following settings in my launch.json file:
{  
    "version": "0.2.0",  
    "configurations": [  
        {  
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File with ETL Arguments",  
            "type": "debugpy",  
            "request": "launch",  
            "program": "${file}",  
            "console": "integratedTerminal",  
            "args": [  
             (  ---some args i need) 
            ],  
            "cwd": "C:\\projects\\defmet",  
            "env": {  
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/defmet_data_piplines"  
            }  
        }  
    ]  
}  

What I Have Tried
I verified that the directory structure is correct and that the defmet_data_piplines/ directory is indeed in the project root.
I checked that my virtual environment is activated and that all necessary packages are installed.
I tried setting the PYTHONPATH in the launch.json to include the path to the module and setting the cwd although the directory I open (in the VS Code) is defmet/.
What could be causing this ModuleNotFoundError, and how can I resolve it? Any guidance on correctly configuring my project environment in Visual Studio Code would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I have the error on this line:
from defmet_data_piplines.app.data_pipeline_factory.data_pipeline_factory import DataPipelineFactory


I use Python 3.13

Thank you!

Have you tried setting PYTHONPATH to "${workspaceFolder}"? The PYTHONPATH environment variable should point to the root from where you are starting to import packages. So, as you have defmet_data_piplines as a package and you are trying to import it, it's its parent that should be set as PYTHONPATH.

Current now i tryed and it works!!!!
Can you explain me why? and why "cwd" didn't help?

Happy it worked! :) Reason is that cwd is useful for setting from which folder is the script being run. For instance, if you try to read a file with a relative path inside your script, that path will be created over that cwd. However, Python does not use your cwd as search path by default, so you need to anyway specify the PYTHONPATH. In this case both paths must be the same, as your working directory is containing the modules you want to import.

You can ignore launch.json and use sys.path as follows. sys.path takes precedence over launch.json
import sys
import os

# Get the current folder of main.py
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# move 2 folders up to 'C:\projects\defmet'
project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, "../.."))

# Append the project root to sys.path
sys.path.append(project_root)

# Import defmet_data_pipelines
import defmet_data_piplines as ddp

# Use defmet_data_piplines 
ddp.some_function()


I would personally not recommend messing with sys.path if an external configuration can set things up for you. Keeping code environment-agnostic when possible makes it look always cleaner.

Agreed. Pythons beauty is flexibility. Upto what extent one to adapt varies from person to person.

Where to puth this code? in the main?

yes, In the main.py
